# Session not passing dropdown selected element to other php script

Tags: php, session, drop-down-menu

First php script -

```
<?php
 session_start(); 
?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body><form method = "post">
<select name="feature" id="feature">
        <?php
        ?>
        <option value > Select Feature</option>
        <?php
        foreach($newFeature as $feat)
        {
            ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $feat;?>"><?php echo $feat;?></option>
            <?php
       }
         ?>
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
    $_SESSION['feature'] = $feature;    
 ?>
```

second php script -

```
<?php
session_start(); 
echo $_SESSION['feature'];
?>
```

When I run second php script, I get **Array** as echoed element instead of the element I selected.
What is wrong with the logic here ?

Please guide.

Comment: where do you get the post/get value?

Comment: What is $feature? Where it is defined??

Comment: You need to submit the form and then get it through `$_POST`

Comment: is $feature supposed to be the selected option?

Comment: @UglyEddie - yes it is.

Answer (score 2):

You have to submit the select. It is impossible to set `$feature` at that moment because the user hasn't yet selected anything.

```
<form method = "post">
<select name="feature" id="feature">
        <option value > Select Feature</option>
        <?php foreach($newFeature as $feat) : ?>
           <option value="<?php echo $feat;?>" <?= $feat == $_SESSION['feature'] : " selected = 'selected'" : "" ?>><?php echo $feat;?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="send" name="mySubmit" />
</form>
```

When you hit 'send' you can get the value by using `$_POST['feature'];` on the same page. If you want to go to another page you have to set the form `action` property.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['feature'] = $_POST['feature'];
```

After the submit the page will 'reload'. Check if `mySubmit` is set and set the `$_SESSION['feature']`(don't forget to start your session at top of the page):

```
if (isset($_POST['mySubmit'])){
   $_SESSION['feature'] = $_POST['feature'];
}
```

Comment: without using action cant I send `$_POST['feature'];` to another page ?

Comment: When you are leaving `action` blank, it will request the same page as you are on.

Comment: here I want to store this value `$_POST['feature'];` in a variable so that I can use across multiple other script and so i want to use session